# Is it safe to not use the constructor when push_back the Iterator of vector<class> to vector?

Tags: c++, vector, iterator

First of all, both are code with no errors.

1.

```cpp
std::vector<HttpConfigLocation> m_postLocation;
std::vector<HttpConfigLocation> location_block = this->m_server_block.get_m_location_block();
std::vector<HttpConfigLocation>::const_iterator location_iter = location_block.begin();

this->m_postLocation.push_back(*location_iter);
```

2. 

```cpp
std::vector<HttpConfigLocation> m_postLocation;
std::vector<HttpConfigLocation> location_block = this->m_server_block.get_m_location_block();
std::vector<HttpConfigLocation>::const_iterator location_iter = location_block.begin();

this->m_postLocation.push_back(HttpConfigLocation(*location_iter));
```

In the motion of the vector's push_back, the pointers could not be moved, so I encountered the background of emplace. So, I had to create it with a constructor, but I had a question. If I just put the iterator as push_back, is the value maintained safe?

Comment: Both will make a copy, but if you use the second version you will get an extra move.

Comment: please post a [mcve].

Comment: @largest_prime_is_463035818 This is a theoretical question.. and It's too big to make... I haven't posted it separately.. sorry but I'll replace it with a Git address..! https://github.com/ftinx/webserv/blob/feature/holee/srcs/Server.cpp#L120

Comment: you only need to add a declaration for the vectors, thats basically all that is missing. I am not asking for more than 2 lines

Comment: @largest_prime_is_463035818 You wasn't asking me to show the working code! Thanks for explaining.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. super, largest_prime_is_463035818.